# Subsetting winter (Dez, Jan, Feb) from daily time series (zoo)

Tags: r, subset, zoo

I have a daily zoo (xts) with a few decades of data in the following format:

```
head(almorol)
1973-10-02 1973-10-03 1973-10-04 1973-10-05 1973-10-06 1973-10-07
     183.9      208.2      153.7       84.8       52.5       35.5
```

and I would like to plot just winter data (the full months of December, January and February). I found the subsetting for xts so I thought I could extract all the Decembers using:

```
x<-apply.yearly(almorol, FUN=last(almorol, "1 month"))
```

and then do something similar for Jan and Feb, but I get the following error:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) :
object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found
```

I can use the `apply.yearly` and `last(almorol, "1 month")` separately but when I combine them it doesn't work.  Does anyone know a way of subsetting those 3 months of the time series? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please use `dput(head(almorol))` to provide sample of your data. And maybe `dput(head(almorol,15))`

Comment: dput(head(almorol,15))   
structure(c(183.9, 208.2, 153.7, 84.8, 52.5, 35.5, 49.2, 77.7, 
73, 104.9, 124.8, 103, 75.9, 108.7, 138.2), index = structure(c(1370, 
1371, 1372, 1373, 1374, 1375, 1376, 1377, 1378, 1379, 1380, 1381, 
1382, 1383, 1384), class = "Date"), class = "zoo")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
z.winter <- z[months(time(z), TRUE) %in% c("Dec", "Jan", "Feb")]
plot(z.winter)
```